# What do you say when people ate the food you cooked until nothing is left?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

What do you say when people ate the food you cooked until nothing is left?

> The corn soup that I made is…

or is there any other expression or sentence form to say for this situation?

Comment: We have an idiom for "ate everything": *licked the platter clean*. I don't have an adverb for you though.

Comment: If you're looking for a word to describe food (or another noun), you want an adjective not an adverb. Certainly "The corn soup that I made is ..." seems to require an adjective.

Comment: In that context, I'd use a _verb_, not an adverb: "The soup was __devoured__."

Comment: How about "gone"?

Comment: "I should have made more!"

Comment: "It'll be a clear day tomorrow!"

Comment: *The corn soup that I made **has proven very popular.***

Comment: Would you be able to provide any extra information about the context the sentence would be used in? For example, why is it not acceptable to use the sentence "People ate the corn soup I cooked until nothing was left."? More details about your goals would help you get more relevant answers.

Comment: "ate the food you cook*ed*". The past *ate* must be matched by the past *cooked*.

Comment: "The corn soup has been _eaten up_" means specifically that it has all been eaten and none is left.

Comment: Apparently I read too much into the question. Are you just looking for an expression to mean the food was eaten up completely, or are you trying to express personal success in a meal that was well liked?

Comment: in my house we use "demolished" :)

Answer (score 10):

A common phrase is [*polish off*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/polish-off):

> **polish off**, *tr. v.*:  to eat or drink something until it is finished

As in:

> My guests polished off the corn soup I made.

Answer (score 3):

One expression for guests who eat all your food is “They ate me out of house and home.”

https://dictionaryblog.cambridge.org/2016/10/19/idioms-and-phrases-related-to-eating/

In your sentence, “The corn soup that I made is ___” *gone* would fit. You could also say that the corn soup has been demolished.

Comment: "They ate me out of house and home" is not really suitable here, because it's negative, and it really refers to the *expense* rather than the food.

Comment: Idiomatically,  [one could say “all gone”](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/all+gone).

Comment: The poster does not indicate whether the event is pleasing or not. so there can be no answer that’s more appropriate than another.

Answer (score 3):

In the specified sentence, I believe the best option would be either:

> The corn soup that I made is gone.

Or:

> The corn soup that I made is finished.

Comment: "Gone" was already suggested by Xanne.

Answer (score 3):

Do you think [eaten up](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eat%20%28something%29%20up) might work?

Comment: I am really surprised that nobody suggested this sooner.

Answer (score 2):

An idiom that I'm certainly familiar with is ' **... lick/ed the pattern off the plate**.'

There are quite a few examples of this hyperbolic (obviously non-literal!) usage on the internet (the verb used may be 'scrape', 'take' ... and an 'almost' may be included); the expression, though not overly common, has a clear meaning. It is used for a single meal (or course). The Jerry Lewis song 'I'm a Little Busybody' {written by Ceon Pober in 1950} [[MadMusic; last verse](https://madmusic.com/song_details.aspx?SongID=5360)], containing the lyrics

- ' ... you lick the pattern off the plate and then you plead for more to eat'

doubtless popularised the usage.

Another example is [['Sunflowers' by Jassmine James; 2015 {Google Books}](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dhZ7CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA60&lpg=PA60&dq=%22licked+the+pattern+off+the+plate%22&source=bl&ots=zrN_uAFOlT&sig=ACfU3U3j9LRBddot0wH6saIo8YHKwWV3PQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiO1JyT3IX8AhVOTcAKHQg2ALs4ChDoAXoECAYQAw#v=onepage&q=%22licked%20the%20pattern%20off%20the%20plate%22&f=false)]:

- 'He thoroughly enjoyed it and nearly licked the pattern off the plate.'

Answer (score 2):

[Finish off](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/finish-off) is quite common:

> If you finish off something that you have been eating or drinking, you eat or drink the last part of it with the result that there is none left.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the phrasal verb **gobble up** (or *gobble sth. up*, sometimes with the preposition *down*).

> The corn soup that I made was gobbled up (by people/guests).

> People gobbled up the corn soup I made.

Here is an example in the wild:

> However, by the time all the shawarmas were served, every other dish in the hotel too was gobbled up by guests. - *[onmanorama.com](https://www.onmanorama.com/food/features/2019/10/02/hotel-offers-free-shawarma-guests-devour-every-dish.html)*

The definition from *[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/gobble-up)*:

> **gobble** sth↔ **up** <sub>phrasal verb *informal*</sub>
>
> **3** to eat something very quickly, especially in an impolite or greedy way 
> *We gobbled up all of the cake in one evening.*

Answer (score -1):

If you are wishing to express that the dish was well liked, you could use ***a big hit***

> Something that is especially successful or positively received.
> <sub>[TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/big+hit)</sub>

or ***a home run***.

> something that exactly succeeds in achieving its goal;
> <sub>[TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/homerun)</sub>

Since soup is kind of like something you drink, you may consider the famous coffee slogan ***good to the last drop***,

> Of a beverage, especially a cup of coffee, having an excellent taste from beginning to end. Typically associated with coffee because of the brand Maxwell House using "Good to the last drop" as its slogan.
> <sub>[TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/good+to%2Ftill+the+last+drop)</sub>

anecdotally credited to Theodore Roosevelt.

> One story has it that the president was asked if he wanted another cup, to which he answered, “Will I have another? Delighted! It’s good to the last drop.”
> <sub>[Eric Troy and CulinaryLore](https://culinarylore.com/drinks:maxwell-house-coffee-and-teddy-roosevelt/)</sub>

So, in your sentence:

> The corn soup that I made was ***a big hit***!
> The corn soup that I made was ***a home run***!
> The corn soup that I made was ***good to the last drop***!